# Behat test don't send the same information on database with a json array

Tags: arrays, json, symfony, testing, behat

In my features when i execute my behat test i send it like this :

```
 And the following user:
 | id  | array                               |
 | ID1 | [{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}] |
```

But in my database i receive this information

```
| id  | array (DC2Type:json_array)                        |
| ID1 | ["[{\"key1\":\"value1\"","\"key2\":\"value2\"}]"] |
```

So i can't use this informations on my array.
Have you got any idea which expression i have to use for have the same informations like tests entries?

I precise i work with symfony 3.4.15, API Platform and PhpMyAdmin

Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Feature files are flexible, but we should avoid adding to much details.

I would hide all unnecessary info from the scenario that doesn't bring any value.

You could hide this information in the feature file and create a method that sets some user details based on some key/parameter identifier.

```
 /**
 * @Then /^I have an (.*) user$/
 */
public function iHaveAUser($user) {
    // generates/gets some data in any format you need
    $dataINeed = generateUser($user);
}
```